# If elif else for python confused

Tags: python

So I’m struggling to get down the coding for an assignment I’m doing I’ve tried so many different ways but I can’t get the code to run correctly.

```
 brand = (input('Please select a brand: ')) 
 brand1 = "Storm"
 brand2 = "Roto-Grip"

    
  
if brand1:
  model= (input('Please select a model: ')) 
storm_G = "Gravity" 
storm_T = "Tropical" 
storm_H = "Hy-Road" 
storm_E = "Electrify"
    
    
if storm_G:
  color = (input('Please select a color: ')) 
G_fire = "Fire" 
G_crimson ="Crimson" 
if color != {G_fire}:
  if color != {G_crimson}:
    print (f'Sorry, {brand1} {storm_G} is only available in {G_fire} and {G_crimson}.')
    
elif storm_T:
  color = (input('Please select a color: ')) 
T_cherry = "Cherry" 
T_rainbow = "Rainbow" 
if color != {T_cherry} and color != {T_rainbow}:
  print (f'Sorry, {brand1} {storm_T} is only available in {T_cherry} and {T_rainbow}.')
```

At first, the first section was running fine but then I moved on to the brand's second model and noticed even if I put the color in correctly the result was the sorry message from both the if and elif statement. Now I can't even get the first code to run correctly. There are going to be 2 more models with 2 different color choices for each and 4 different models (2 colors each) of the second brand. I just need help with these sorry messages that keep popping up. If the user enters in a model but a color that the model does not have then a sorry message should prompt. As I said earlier once I get to the color input on the output no matter what I do I am prompt with the sorry message for both statements,

"Sorry, Storm Gravity is only available in Fire and Crimson."

"Sorry, Storm Tropical is only available in Cherry and Rainbow."

If there's anyone that can help it would truly be appreciated.

Comment: `if brand1` will always be true. `if storm_G` will always be true. You need to use `if brand == brand1` if you want to check equality.

Comment: You should set the variables equal to the input and not set them to the actual values, as they will get evaluated no matter the input.

Comment: Always remember: after an "if" keyword the next expression will be evaluated as true or false. if(1<2) will always be true. And as pointed before, doing an if statement for a single variable (no logical expresion) will result on checking if the variable has a value or if is pointing to null reference.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What textbook or other source are you using to learn Python? What does it say about how `if` works in Python? Where the code says, for example, `if brand1:`, **what do you expect this to mean, and why**? Where the code says `if color != {G_fire}:`, what do you think is the purpose of the `{}`? Why did you **not** instead write, for example, `if {color} != G_fire:`? (That would also be wrong, but I want to *understand the reasoning*.)

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and [mre], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. "If there's anyone that can help it would truly be appreciated." is [not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). When posting here, focus on **one part** of the program and figure out *specifically what you want to know* about it; then *ask a question* - starting with a question word like "why" or "how", and ending with `?`.

Comment: hello, @KarlKnechtel There was a lot more than help would be appreciated I am new to python and in an intro class. Saw people asking questions about their codes on here so made an account real quick to get input. Did not know all the rules of the site will make sure to ask a more concise question in the future if I come back here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel my text book is Starting Out with Python by
Tony Gaddis. I have messed with the code so much I don't remember my initial reason for adding the brackets, the chapter before was about sets. Getting to the elif statement in my current code threw me off so I was starting to add stuff I didn't realize was not necessary a lot of the comments on here have been very helpful with getting me through this and fixing my current errors. In my eyes, I might have added the brackets to G_fire because it was a variable that is not equal to color. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements for checking brand and model are missing the crucial part: the comparison. The part after the if is checked as a boolean. A string that is not empty will convert to `true`, therefore your `if` statement will always be evaluated. You want to compare the input with the provided brands / models like so:

```py
if brand == brand1:
...
if model == storm_G:
...
elif model == storm_T:
...
```

Also, your `if` statements for the colors will not work, because you are creating a `set` when using curly braces. You probably copied that from the print statement. To actually compare the values, it should look like this:

```py
if color != G_fire and color != G_crimson:
  print(f"Sorry...")
```

**Edit:** after your comment, I realized the indentation is all over the place. Try to think about when something should be done. For example, the `model` should only equal `storm_G` if the `brand` also equals `brand1`. Therefore everything should be indented under the `if brand == brand1:`. Same goes for the colors, they should be indented under the if / elif statements for the models.

The resulting program would look something like this:

```py
brand = input('Please select a brand: ')
brand1 = "Storm"
brand2 = "Roto-Grip"

if brand == brand1:
  model = input('Please select a model: ')
  storm_G = "Gravity" 
  storm_T = "Tropical" 
  storm_H = "Hy-Road" 
  storm_E = "Electrify"
    
  if model == storm_G:
    color = (input('Please select a color: ')) 
    G_fire = "Fire"
    G_crimson ="Crimson" 
    if color != G_fire and color != {G_crimson}:
      print (f'Sorry, {brand1} {storm_G} is only available in {G_fire} and {G_crimson}.')
    
  elif model == storm_T:
    color = (input('Please select a color: ')) 
    T_cherry = "Cherry" 
    T_rainbow = "Rainbow" 
    if color != T_cherry and color != T_rainbow:
      print (f'Sorry, {brand1} {storm_T} is only available in {T_cherry} and {T_rainbow}.')
```

Comment: I believe your edit is the actual answer. The if statements without comparison could stay as some beginner form of null checking.

Comment: @root I think both problems are relevant. Null checking would only make sense, if it was the input that was in the if statemen. Also the question says that they need to extend the program to models of the other brand as well, in which case the full if statements are needed.

Comment: I forgot if statements required == to compare but when taking the brackets off I am met with just the sorry statement for my second model/elif statement, even though I am using inputs from my first model/if statement.

Comment: I didn't see before, but your indentation is all over the place. Try to think about when something should be done. For example, the `model` should only equal `storm_G` if the `brand` also equals `brand1`. Therefore everything should be indented under the `if brand == brand1:`. Same goes for the colors, they should be indented under the if / elif statements for the models

Comment: If there are many things wrong with the code (and there are) and the only guidance for how to answer is "If there's anyone that can help it would truly be appreciated.", then there is **not a question** that is on topic for Stack Overflow, and thus answers should not be attempted (per [answer]). Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: ahhh okay I'll take more look over the indentation, thank you @JeanotZubler